# Text twitches on hover

Tags: css

Currently learning CSS and here is task: make rhombus button which change its direction on hover. I did it but the button twitching its text on hover. Is it possible to fix this? Currently I stuck. I tried to search, but nothing found.

```css
.button {
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 12px 56px;
}

/* This is my attempt to fix it. It worked. Partially :\ */
.button > .span {
  display: block;
  transition: 0s;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
            
.button:hover > .span {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
            
.button:hover {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
            
.button-yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="span">I shouldn't twitch on hover</span>
</button>
```

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: I love the glitchy version more than the "fixed" versions. That looks trippy.

Comment: probably don't do `transition: 0s`, I think setting it the same as the parent element should be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transition` time of the text skew needs to match the `transition` time of the button skew. When I set them both to `0.2s`, they cancel each other out as intended.

```css
.button {
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 12px 56px;
}

/* This is my attempt to fix it. It worked. Partially :\ */
.button > .span {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
            
.button:hover > .span {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
            
.button:hover {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
            
.button-yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="span">I shouldn't twitch on hover</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I would consider `transition:inherit` to make sure it's *always* the same

Answer (score 2):

Consider a pseudo element to avoid this bad effect:

```css
.button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 56px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
.button:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transition:0.2s;
}
           
.button:hover::before {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
/* in case you want to keep the outline effect of the button*/
.button:active::before,
.button:focus::before {
  outline:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="span">I shouldn't twitch on hover</span>
</button>
```